# How to implement blurred background for Modal Bottome Sheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am working with Modal Bottom sheet and want to give blurred background, but the type of the parameter *barriercolor* is Color, so I cannot use BackdropFiter().
Does anyone know how to implement blurred background for Modal Bottom Sheet??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update:
Sorry for my careless.
You can set `backgroundColor:Colors.transparent` and `expand:true` and make your own `barrier` in `builder`.

It may look like this:

```dart
showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      expand: true,
      builder: (context) => BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 20, sigmaY: 20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Text('Im child'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, but it is quiet different from what I wanted. I want the barrier part to be blurred, not the sheet part.

Comment: You can make a "full screen bottom sheet" and make the whole background barrier.

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is I cannot dismiss the bottom sheet by tapping the barrier part since the barrier part is "bottom sheet".

Comment: Wrap the whole widget with a `GestureDetector`,  and `onTap:(){Navigator.of(context).pop();}`. It means that, where you want to 'tap to dismiss', where have a `GestureDetector` wrapped.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know  "Navigator.of(context).pop()" can dismiss the bottom sheet!!

Comment: `Navigator.of(context).pop()` can dismiss a dialog.